# dask-image ndfilter.maximum_filter memory error issue when using a circle footprint

Tags: python, scipy, dask

When I'm trying to run a neighborhood analysis `dask_image.ndfilters.maximum_filter()` on a quite big geotiff file (~7GB / 30000x50000 px) but also small ones (800x800 px) using a circle pattern for the footprint attribute I get a **MemoryError**. I get the memory error when computing `.compute()` the dask array back to a numpy array.

This occurs when using big radius for the circle pattern (> 100). When I'm using smaller circle patterns or size instead of footprint the system is not running out of memory so I think handling the circle pattern floods the RAM.

I have tried to chunk both the input array aswell as the circle array (i converted the circle array to a dask array) but still getting MemoryErrors.

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
import dask_image.imread
import dask_image.ndfilters

cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=1,
                       threads_per_worker=1,
                       memory_target_fraction=0.98,
                       memory_limit='32GB')

client = Client(cluster)
client

# Import raster file as dask array
raster_path = "data_file.tif"
raster_data = dask_image.imread.imread(raster_path)
raster_data = np.squeeze(raster_data, axis=0)

radius = 300

# Create a circle filter for the neighbor analysis
circle_filter = np.zeros((2*radius+1, 2*radius+1), dtype=int)
y, x = np.ogrid[-radius:radius+1, -radius:radius+1]
mask = x**2 + y**2 <= radius**2
circle_filter[mask] = 1
circle_filter = da.from_array(circle_filter)

# Calculate max value in neighorhood
max_value = dask_image.ndfilters.maximum_filter(raster_data, footprint=circle_filter, mode='nearest')

# Convert dask array to numpy array
output = max_value.compute()
```

My overall goal is to export the array back to a GeoTIFF.

Any suggestions how to handle neighborhood analysis with large circled patterns?

Comment: Not quite following what you’re trying to do - if you want help please include a full example as a [mre] instead of just a few example lines. Also do include the chunked version of the code and any tracebacks. But a couple things jump out. 1) .compute() executes all scheduled operations, so the fact that the memory error happens there is not surprising - it just means there is a too-large array required by the result or any previous scheduled operation. 2) using 1 worker and 1 thread means you’re doing everything in series - nothing is in parallel.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado: Thank you for your suggestions! I've updated the code example so it can be reproduced. The intention to just use one worker was to not run out of memory because the one worker can be assigned more RAM. But I'm new to the dask world and not really deep into the proper workflows so far.

Comment: Could you also provide some input data, or at least a link to a TIF file that triggers the issue?

Comment: @GuillaumeEB: I used a clip of this dataset: [DEM Austria 10m](https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/land-ktn_digitales-gelandemodell-dgm-osterreich). Also tested (and failed) with this dataset [DEM Upper Austria 1m](https://e-gov.ooe.gv.at/at.gv.ooe.intramapgem/dop/downloads/40704/40704_DGM_tif.zip).